# Hadoop httpFS always returns HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Tags: hadoop, fiware-cosmos

I have a problem with HttpFS service of hadoop.When i try to curl some resource:

```
curl -i http://192.168.4.180:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/hadoop/?op=LISTSTATUS
```

the response i get is:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 17 Aug 2015 08:57:47 GMT
```

But when i try to do the same with webhdfs it works:

```
 curl -i http://192.168.4.180:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/hadoop/?op=LISTSTATUS 

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
and so on ....
```

Httpfs service is running on port 14000, i have checked it via nmap.
Any suggestions or ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find the reason for it and a solution to it?

Comment: Take a look at this article:
https://streever.atlassian.net/wiki/display/HADOOP/HTTPFS+-+Configure+and+Run+with+HDP+2.2.4.x

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem. And solved by this [link](https://streever.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/HADOOP/pages/20774914/HTTPFS+-+Configure+and+Run+with+HDP+2.3.x)

In brief, you need to add the symbol link:

```
# Point to the 'webapps' in current.
cd /etc/hadoop-httpfs/tomcat-deployment
ln -s /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-httpfs/webapps webapps
```